# How pywt calculates dwt Haar coefficients?

Tags: wavelet-transform, haar-wavelet, dwt, pywavelets, pywt

I got this example of a
[1D Haar wavelet transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rZ9b.png) from a book.

"The Haar wavelet transform of [11, 9, 5, 7] is given by [8, 2, 1, −1]."

When I calculate the same data with python PyWavelets (pywt) library I get different coefficients.

Is pywt normalizing the coefficients? Is there a documentation on the normalization process?

Here is my code:

```
import pywt

x = [11,9,5,7]

cA, cD = pywt.dwt(x, 'haar')
y = pywt.idwt(cA, cD, 'haar')

print(cA)
print(cD)
print(y)
```

and the result is:

```
[14.14213562  8.48528137]
[ 1.41421356 -1.41421356]
[11.  9.  5.  7.]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is called [the normalization](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/what-does-the-normalization-step-of-the-haar-wavelet-transform-represent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DaBler had the answer. Calculating the values as indicated [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/what-does-the-normalization-step-of-the-haar-wavelet-transform-represent) I get the same result on resolution 2 as with pywt.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).